# How to fix "Element with locator not found" in robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

I need to write a script where I can search  with a keyword and test if a certain subject will show but I cannot manage to get the search id.  This is my script.

```
*** Settings ***
 Library    SeleniumLibrary
 Suite Setup     Go to homepage
 Suite Teardown     Close All Browsers

 *** Variables ***
 ${HOMEPAGE}     https://www.mdh.se/utbildning/kurser
 ${BROWSER}      chrome

 *** Test Cases ***
 Google cloud and find Industrial Systems in Cloud Computing
  Google and check results         cloud       Industrial Systems in Cloud Computing

 *** Keywords ***
 Google and check results
  [Arguments]         ${searchkey}        ${result}
 Input Text     id=occasionsTableen_UK_filter     ${searchkey}
 Wait Until Page Contains      ${result}
 Go to homepage
  Open Browser     ${HOMEPAGE}     ${BROWSER}
```

And this is the error message

```
 Google cloud and find Industrial Systems in Cloud Computing           | FAIL |
 Element with locator 'id=occasionsTableen_UK_filter' not found.
```

Comment: Tried simply to remove the 'id='? Does that help?

Comment: Element with locator 'occasionsTableen_UK_filter' not found. @Rotrak Thats what it says now

Comment: you could you try it with xpath://*[@id="occasionsTableen_UK_filter"]/label/input

Answer (score 4):

The error is telling you it can't find the element.

There are several reasons that could happen. It could truly not be on the page. Or, it could be that it's not initially on the page but is added asynchronously at some point after your test runs. Or, the element could be inside an iframe. Or, you could be on a different page than you are assuming you're on due to an error or a redirect that you didn't anticipate.

Each of those problems requires a different solution. You may simply have an incorrect locator, in which case you need to determine what the correct locator is and use it instead. Or, you may need to call [Wait until page contains element](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Page%20Contains%20Element) before calling `input text`. Or, you might need to call [Select frame](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame) to switch to an embedded frame. Or, you might need to verify you are on the correct page before calling `input text`.

Comment: In my case the age use an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The page does not have an element with that ID. You can check that easily with Chrome's developer's tool -> elements and then `Ctrl+F` to search for elements by ID, classes, xpaths, etc..

[image: Chrome find element]

Comment: When I inspect the search bar this is what I get and thats why I dont know how to call it as it doesnt have a name or id.   @asprtrmp                                                                
           `<input type="search" class="" placeholder="Search courses" aria- 
           controls="occasionsTableen_UK">`

Comment: For me the element's attribute is `occasionsTablesv_SE`. But you can use xpath based on attribute value, e.g, the locator usage in Selenium would be like `xpath=//input[@aria-controls='occasionsTablesv_SE']`

Answer (score 0):

The xpath is incorrect!
use chrome press F12 and copy xpath to the right element.
yours should be like this //*[@ id = "occasionTableen_UK_filter"]

Example xpath with id:
// * [@ id = "name"]